# Haxe - Standard library not found

Tags: haxe

I finally set up the haxe in visual studio code,
and it says 'Standard library not found.' and so on.

It says that I should check the 'HAXE_STD_PATH' environment variable, but I tried setting it somewhere like: %HAXEPATH%\haxelib, %HAXEPATH%\std, or just %HAXEPATH%. and it still didn't work. The way that I downloaded was:

I firstly downloaded binary version for Windows 64-bit, and there *wasn't* neko.dll support! So I downloaded it independently. And I downloaded codedox and all extensions made by Kode. And I tried to run command "haxe ./build.hxml" in powershell. And this happened.

Also, my OS is windows.

Comment: `%HAXEPATH%\lib` being empty is normal if you haven't installed any Haxelibs yet.

Comment: how did you install Haxe?

Comment: which platform might also help

Comment: @LaurenceTaylor the way of installing, and platform, I wrote them now.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I fixed it! I didn't close and reopen the vscode, when I set the environment variable to %HAXEPATH%\std.